# How to convert non-traditional formatted Pandas date object to datetime

Tags: python, pandas

I have an interesting scenario where a date object looks like the following:

```
'6/7/2018 7:59:11 PM'
```

in the format m/d/yyyy h:mm:ss PM (or AM). Note that the month and hour is not padded with a zero. I have tried the following line of code using a Pandas date object:

```
data = pd.read_csv('file.txt', sep="\t", header=None, dtype = 'str')

data.columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', ...]
```

The data.columns provides a look at the format of the file, all tab-delimited (note that is not an actual line of code, just an arbitrary way to show how the columns were labeled). The time series are in Column A. I attempted the conversion using:

```
time = pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(data['A']), format = '%-m/%-d/%Y %-H/%M/%S %p')
```

The return is:

```
ValueError: '-' is a bad directive in format '%-m/%-d/%Y %-H/%M/%S %p'
```

Any suggestions on how to go about resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(df['A'])`?

Comment: Yup, small internal error I didn't realize until now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your datetime string is `'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p'`

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({"A": ['6/7/2018 7:59:11 PM' ]})
time = pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(data['A']), format = '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p')
print( time )
```

**Output:**

```
0   2018-06-07 07:59:11
Name: A, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Didn't see that I typed the format incorrectly, also found another small internal error in the code. Thanks again!